# How to print a variable from a function at python prompt

Tags: python, function, printing

There are various python files in a directory and all these contain a function desciption() as follows :

```
def description():
    desc = 'something'
    return desc
```

Now I have main.py as follows :

```
def a():
    pth = os.listdir('homedir/workspace')
    for filename in pth :
        exec "import " + filename
        desc = eval(filename + '.desciption()')
    print desc
```

Right now when I run python main.py, nothing happens. How do I print this desc when I run python main.py?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the import worked, and that you have imported a module called `filename` in each iteration, then you *could* get the module by name, and call its `descrpition()` method:

```
import sys
mod = sys.modules[filename]
print mod.description()
```

But note that it may make more sense to print the module's pydocs:

```
print mod.__doc__
```

Comment: only after seeing your code I realized what OP wanted... that's what I love about Python, good code is more descriptive than any explanation!

Comment: @m.wasowski I haven't figured out what OP wants yet :-) But your way of loading the modules seems better.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close quotes properly in this line:

```
pth = os.listdir('homedir/workspace)
```

Also you should not use eval here:

```
desc = eval(filename + '.desciption()')
```

and I assume you wanted to import by variable here:

```
        exec "import " + filename
```

This is how it should look like:

```
def a():
    import importlib

    pth = os.listdir('homedir/workspace')
    for filename in pth :
        mdl = importlib.import_module(os.path.splitext(filename)[0])
        desc = mdl.description()
        print desc
```

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext

Answer (score 0):

1. You missed the closing ' in the pth variable
2. You've referenced desc on the last line without declaring it first.
   Start your function with `desc = None`

Answer (score 0):

```
def a():
    pth = os.listdir('homedir/workspace')

    for filename in pth:
        module_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        exec "import " + module_name
        desc = eval(module_name + '.description()')
        print desc
```

make sure the main.py located at the same path with your modules. or add it to sys path by

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"homedir/workspace")
```